# Codeigniter session not being destroyed after window close in firefox

Tags: codeigniter, session, firefox

I am usnig codeigniter 2.2 and this is my config setting:

```
$config['sess_cookie_name']     = 'ci_session';
$config['sess_expiration']      = 0;
$config['sess_expire_on_close'] = TRUE;
$config['sess_encrypt_cookie']  = FALSE;
$config['sess_use_database']    = FALSE;
$config['sess_table_name']      = 'ci_sessions';
$config['sess_match_ip']        = FALSE;
$config['sess_match_useragent'] = TRUE;
$config['sess_time_to_update']  = 300;
```

Why is Mozilla Firefox not destroying my session after i close the window?It works fine in Chrome.

Comment: Try disabling the "sess_match_useragent". I think it's a problem with Firefox though, not CI.

Comment: @Craig i've set it to FALSE and the problem is still the same

Comment: Firefox user-agent might be larger than the data type in the database. 'ci-sessions'. Change the user agent to something like `varchar(250)`

Comment: @Philip i haven't created that table i am just using the session library

Comment: Create the database and see what happens, or set `$config['sess_match_useragent'] = false` and clear browser cache.

Comment: Your session sess_expiration is set to 0 so I think will close straight away should be at 1440 or 7200

Comment: @Philip i've set $config['sess_match_useragent']=false and cleared my browser cache and now my session lasts for certain amount of hours.Last night it was there and today is gone.Now i tested it again and it is present when i close the browser so it will probably be gone tomorrow..i wonder how could it be like that when my $config['sess_expiration']='0'

Comment: Ok I had a look through the system files, basically `Session` class is setting `sess_expiration` to two years in the future if you set it to `zero` in the config file. The problem however it seems is the `cookie` is not getting reset/removed hence the persistent session data.  You can try set `$config['sess_expiration'] = 300 and hope hope for the best, else you may have to modify the `Session` library.

Comment: @Philip ok i'll try with 300

Comment: You could also try set it to a negative number `$config['sess_expiration'] = -1`